# How to save a sentence in a text file in c++?

Tags: c++

This is what I have, this program runs ok as it stands, the only problem I am having is that it will not save the approriate sentence in File3.txt. I included the entire program for understanding, what is it that I am not doing correctly that is preventing the sentence under the case option 'r' to not save? Thanks.

```
void ascii (int number);
bool raffle (int number);
const int cArray=5;




int main () 
{       

    int value;

    char option;

while (1)
{


    cout <<"Enter a positive integer number: " <<endl;
    cin >>value;
    cout <<endl;


    cout <<"A[scii]" "\t\tR[affle]" "\t\tE[xit]" <<endl;
    cout <<"Please select an option: " <<endl;
    cin >>option;
    cout<<endl;

    switch (option)
    {
        case 'a':
        case 'A':

            ascii(value);
            break;

        case 'r':
        case 'R':
            ofstream outfile("G:/File3.txt", ios::out);
            if(!outfile)
            {
                cout<<"File could not be opened"<<endl;
                exit(1);
            }
            if (raffle(value)==1)
            {
                outfile<<"The number "<<value<<"is present in the array."<<endl;
            }
            else
            {
                outfile<<"The number "<<value<<"is not present in the array."<<endl;
            }
            outfile.close();
            break;

        case 'e':
        case 'E':

            return 0;
            break;


    }
}
}


void ascii (int value)
{

    if (48 <= value && value <= 57)
    {
        cout <<"The number you have entered corresponds to a digit in the ASCII table." <<endl;
    }
    else if(65 <= value && value <= 90)
    {
        cout <<"The number you have entered corresponds to an uppercase letter in the ASCII table." <<endl;
    }
    else if (97 <= value && value <= 122)
    {
        cout <<"The number you have entered corresponds to a lowercase letter in the ASCII table." <<endl;
    }
    else  
    {
        cout <<"The number you have entered corresponds to none of the above." << endl;
    }

}

bool raffle (int value)
{   
    int random[cArray];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        random[i]= 0+rand()%(100+1-0);
        cout<<random[i]<<" "<<endl;
    }

    for (int j=0; j<5; j++)
    {
        if (value == random[j])
        {
            cout << "\n" <<j<<endl;

            return true;
        }
    }
            cout << "Number not present."<<endl;
            return false;



}
```

Comment: Did you confirm that the code gets to the point where you open the file? Did you confirm that the file actually gets opened? Does the file actually exist? What is in it?

Comment: There is nothing in the file, and the file does exist, what I am supposed to do is put one of those senteces in the that file. If the number chosen is in fact present in the array, then that sentence is supposed to be put in, ect ect if it's not. Am I supposed to open the file first in order for it to be put in and then it will print in the file?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you forget `outfile.open()` ..

UPDATE:
Ok, got the problem here (a subtle one). You shouldn't declare ofstream in the switch case statement. Instead declare it like this:

```
    int value;
ofstream outfile("G:/File3.txt", ios::out);
    char option = 'r';


    switch (option)
    {
        case 'r':
        case 'R':

            if(!outfile.is_open())
            {
                cout<<"File could not be opened"<<endl;
                exit(1);
            }
            if (raffle(value)==1)
            {
                outfile<<"The number "<<value<<"is present in the array."<<endl;
            }
            else
            {
                outfile<<"The number "<<value<<"is not present in the array."<<endl;
            }

            break;

case 'e' :
case 'E' :
break;
    }
outfile.close();
return 0;
```

And always return value if you declare int main ()
Full version of the modified code is [here](http://codepad.org/0TlL6M1o).

Comment: There is nothing in the file, and the file does exist, what I am supposed to do is put one of those senteces in the that file. If the number chosen is in fact present in the array, then that sentence is supposed to be put in, ect ect if it's not. Am I supposed to open the file first in order for it to be put in and then it will print in the file?

Comment: Yes, you must open it first. Take a look at here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Comment: Hmm, well I added the outfile.open and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry for my quick judgement. The problem doesn't rise from open() because you have state the file name already. It's because when you use the break, it doesn't break out the while(1). And the main function have no return value in some cases.

Comment: You may want to take a look at a modified version here: http://codepad.org/7JoosIc4 . I removed case 'e', because it raises error on the online compiler. I still not understand why it cause troubles.

Comment: OK, wait, I'm confused. When I open File3, which is saved in notepad, it comes up blank. That's not supposed to happen. I modified it as yours is and its still blank

Comment: Did you try to drop the "exit(1);" statement to see if the file is opened? Oh, and try replace your file by "G:\\test.txt" for example. Using "\\" instead of "\" for folder delimiter.

Comment: AHH! I did all of those, and nothing still! The file still keeps coming up blank. I'm not too sure what's going on, I have it saved on my flash drive, and everytime I run the program and exit it, my flash drives, like it's saving, but it just comes up blank.

Comment: Please try to be patient, or relax a little time before tackling the problem again. If you droped the exit(1);, did it show you: "File could not be opened"? I can't test it myself because I only have an online compiler, which doesn't grant me priledge of saving files on their computer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified code ::

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void ascii (int number);
bool raffle (int number);
const int cArray=5;

int main ()
{

    int value;

    char option;

while (1)
{


    cout <<"Enter a positive integer number: " <<endl;
    cin >>value;
    cout <<endl;


    cout <<"A[scii]" "\t\tR[affle]" "\t\tE[xit]" <<endl;
    cout <<"Please select an option: " <<endl;
    cin >>option;
    cout<<endl;

    ofstream outfile("./File3.txt", ios::out);

    switch (tolower(option))
    {
        case 'a':

            ascii(value);
            break;
        case 'r':
            if(!outfile)
            {
                cout<<"File could not be opened"<<endl;
                exit(1);
            }
            if (raffle(value)==1)
            {
                outfile<<"The number "<<value<<"is present in the array."<<endl;
            }
            else
            {
                outfile<<"The number "<<value<<"is not present in the array."<<endl;
            }
            outfile.close();
            break;

        case 'e':
                return 0;
            break;


    }
        }

        return 0;
}


void ascii (int value)
{

    if (48 <= value && value <= 57)
    {
        cout <<"The number you have entered corresponds to a digit in the ASCII table." <<endl;
    }
    else if(65 <= value && value <= 90)
    {
        cout <<"The number you have entered corresponds to an uppercase letter in the ASCII table." <<endl;
    }
    else if (97 <= value && value <= 122)
    {
        cout <<"The number you have entered corresponds to a lowercase letter in the ASCII table." <<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout <<"The number you have entered corresponds to none of the above." << endl;
    }

}

bool raffle (int value)
{
    int random[cArray];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        random[i]= 0+rand()%(100+1-0);
        cout<<random[i]<<" "<<endl;
    }

    for (int j=0; j<5; j++)
    {
        if (value == random[j])
        {
            cout << "\n" <<j<<endl;

            return true;
        }
    }
            cout << "Number not present."<<endl;
            return false;
}
```

The problem I think was with declaring a stream in side only one of the case branches..which makes an unsafe variable / stream.
The code is working for me in Linux

Answer (score 0):

Hello to all who have helped me try to solve this problem. I found out that the switch and fstream were incompatible, so I changed my cases to if() and else if() statements, and instead of having my (raffle(value==1) i changed it to (raffle(value==true) and it works! So once again, thank you all for your replies, esp you Hoang Long!
-Maria :D